# polymorphic relationships and interfaces/abstract classes/protocols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model `Comments` that I associate with almost every other model. I have comments index page where I use the title of the model, which I call `commentable`.

What is the best way to ensure that the `commentable` model has a method or attribute called `:title`?

In Objective-C I would define a protocol and in other languages I would define an abstract class or interface. I'm trying to figure out the best way of writing maintainable rails code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a method on the comments model that does this for you. So in comments.rb:

```
def title
  self.commentable.title if self.commentable.respond_to?(:title)
end
```

In your view, you can check if the comment has a title and render it, or else just skip rendering:

```
<% if @commentable.title %>
  <h2><%= @commentable.title %></h2>
<% end %>
```

It's not exactly a protocol or interface, but in Ruby you can't easily mandate that objects act in a certain way. You use things like respond_to? to see if they do, and if so, then you act.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach.